# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'FY2017M7' to data type int

Tags: sql

I have a `column` called fiscal_month which is in this format "FY2016M12", I am trying to extract only the part 'M12' so i am using this code

```
select *,
(right([FISCAL_MONTH],len([FISCAL_MONTH]-charindex('M',[FISCAL_MONTH])))) as Month_NUM
from 
Dispatch_Fact_Intermediate
```

I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'FY2017M7' to
>   data type int.

Comment: You have a typo. `len([FISCAL_MONTH]` should be `len([FISCAL_MONTH])` (and another closing brace should be removed). I *think* that's all there is to it, and as such I think this question can be closed.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a parentheses error:

```
select dfi.*,
       right([FISCAL_MONTH],
             len([FISCAL_MONTH]) - charindex('M', [FISCAL_MONTH]))
            ) as Month_NUM
from Dispatch_Fact_Intermediate dfi;
```

If your data is in this format, why not just use `right([FISCAL_MONTH], 2)`?

Comment: `right([FISCAL_MONTH], 2)` would work for `M01`...`M12`, but not for `M1`...`M12`. The OP has an example of `M7`.